# Azure PowerShell Copy-AzStorageBlob: Invalid parameter: comp

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to copy blobs between storage accounts using `Copy-AzStorageBlob` command.

```
$srcCtx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $srcStorageAccountName -SasToken $srcSasToken
$destCtx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $destStorageAccountName -SasToken $destSasToken

Copy-AzStorageBlob -SrcBlob "blobPath" -SrcContainer "src" -Context $srcCtx -DestContainer "dest" -DestContext $destCtx
```

and I get an error that the following parameter is invalid:

```
QueryParameterName: comp
QueryParameterValue: tags
```

but I am not using them directly.  Do you have any idea what is wrong? I would like to underline, that source and destination context are working - I have read and write some blobs using mentioned contexts. The issue occurs only during blob copying.

The error message:

```
Copy-AzStorageBlob: Value for one of the query parameters specified in the request URI is invalid.
RequestId:d705aed0-b01e-0013-12c6-244430000000
Time:2022-02-18T12:56:40.1603279Z
Status: 400 (Value for one of the query parameters specified in the request URI is invalid.)
ErrorCode: InvalidQueryParameterValue
Additional Information:
QueryParameterName: comp
QueryParameterValue: tags
Reason:
Content:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidQueryParameterValue</Code><Message>Value for one of the query parameters specified in the request URI is invalid.
RequestId:d705aed0-b01e-0013-12c6-244430000000
Time:2022-02-18T12:56:40.1603279Z</Message><QueryParameterName>comp</QueryParameterName><QueryParameterValue>tags</QueryParameterValue><Reason /></Error>
Headers:
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: d705aed0-b01e-0013-12c6-244430000000
x-ms-client-request-id: f76e9297-504e-42a7-8c86-54ad81bedad7
x-ms-error-code: InvalidQueryParameterValue
Date: Fri, 18 Feb 2022 12:56:40 GMT
Content-Length: 375
Content-Type: application/xml
```

Comment: Can you run your cmdlet with `-Debug` and `-Verbose` switch parameters? This should give you more details about the request/response.

Comment: Unfortunetly, there are not any usefull information after unabled Debug and Vebose. ```DEBUG: 15:12:13 - CopyAzureStorageBlob end processing, Start 1149 remote calls. Finish 1148 remote calls. Elapsed time 11326153.03 ms. Client operation id: Azure-Storage-PowerShell-a503cf6a-ad22-4b08-aef8-1fcf5c35b20e.        
DEBUG: 15:12:13 - CopyAzureStorageBlob end processing.
VERBOSE: Transfer Summary
--------------------------------
Total:  1.
Successful: 0.
Failed: 1.```

Comment: @skolukmar : can you please try giving single quotes to source and destination context i.e; like  '$srcCtx' and try if thoseare variables and has vaule assigned to them and please make sure those vaules are correct

Comment: @kavyasaraboju-MT I believe,  the context is right, because it has been already used in other command in the same script.  The issue occurs only for `Copy-AzStorageBlob`.  I've checked settings via `Write-Output $srcCtx` and it looks fine. Regarding putting the $srcCtx to single quotes I get an message: `Cannot bind parameter 'Context'. Cannot convert the "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.AzureStorageContext" value of type "System.String" to type "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.IStorageContext".`.

Comment: @skolukmar : what was the cause of the issue and how it got resolved?

Comment: @kavyasaraboju-MT The issue has been partially resolved - now I am getting an `AuthenticationFailed` error. I've replaced % that occurs in SASToken with %% manually, so I don't like the solution. I am a bit confused, why the issue occurs with `Copy-AzStorageBlob` command but works fine with `Set-AzStorageBlobContent` or `Get-AzStorageBlob` - exactly the same context definition is used. I suppose, there is

Answer (score 0):

Please try freshly [generating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/generate-sas-tokens) a new SAS key through Azure Portal or Azure Storage Explorer to ensure that the SAS key is fresh  and not expired and copy that in url without whitespaces and also make sure to have the correct permissions ( read, write, list etc) which are required for certain operations.

Make sure to have one of any of below roles tried.

```
1.  Storage Blob Data Contributor
2.  Storage Blob Data Owner
```

Try to upgrade(or downgrade) the package versions of azure.storage.blob
Try to provide  only required headers like  x-ms-blob-type  in your request by  removing all other unneccessary headers  .Check if x-ms-tags header is present and remove if not required.

**References:**

1. [Error -Value for one of
   the query parameters specified in the request URI is invalid - Stack
   Overflow](https://Reference)
2. [Get Blob Tags (REST API) - Azure Storage | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob-tags)
3. [Copy Blob (REST API) - Azure Storage | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/copy-blob)

Comment: I've observed that the issue with invalid permissions exists only with `Copy-AzStorageBlob` when Hierarchical Namespace is enabled. Exactly the same command works properly when it is a BlobStorage (not Data Lake). That would means that `Copy-AzStorageBlob` support BlobStorage only. Does it make sense?